# How to know what company protect a website?

Tags: web-scraping

https://www.genecards.org is protected by cloudflare. But this is not clear from the HTML webpages on genecards.org. Is there a systematically to figure out this kind of information for a number of websites? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Short of triggering a Cloudflare bot challenge, you can try to tell the public-facing CDN/WAF/some of the anti-bot services as follows:
Do an [NS lookup](https://mxtoolbox.com/DNSLookup.aspx) and look for either what nameserver/DNS hosting provider they use (often for Cloudflare customers it's *.ns.cloudflare.com), or what IP's that name resolves to. Both methods are not 100% reliable because that could be only an outer, public-facing layer and inside there could be a non-public facing WAF. IPs can also change. But it's a start.

In this case, for genecards.org it's actually showing not Cloudflare but Imperva Incapsula CDN as the outer layer, based on the IP addresses genecards.org resolves to. A quick check on [builtwith](https://builtwith.com/genecards.org) in the "CDN" section confirms that.

Comment: With `nslookup` I can only see the IP addresses, how to the company info?

Comment: Use my "NS lookup" link above, it shows you the company name underneath the IP (Incapsula Inc (AS19551)). Otherwise, you can use any IP whois tool https://www.ultratools.com/tools/ipWhoisLookup